# How to multiply two string binary numbers from txt file

Tags: python, numpy

Absolute Beginner at Python

Given a .txt file, containing the following data for 1000 rows

```
11010101    10101010 
10101010    10101010
10101000    10101010
```

Where the space is seperates by a tab. I need to multiply the two binary numbers together and then format the data into a `1000x16` matrix such as:

```
[[1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0],
[1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0]].
```

My code (so far):

```
with open(‘file.txt’, ‘r’) in f:  
    dataset= f.read()
    dataset= f.split(’/t’)
```

After this I’m just not sure how to do it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code :

```
result=[]
with open("file.txt", "r") as f:  
    dataset= f.readline()
    while dataset:
        t=dataset.split("\t")
        x=bin(int(t[0],2)*int(t[1],2))
        x=x[2:]
        #if length of result is less than 16 
        if(len(x)<16):
            req=16-len(x)
            y=""
            for i in range(0,req,1):
                y=y+'0'
            y=y+x
            x=y
        result.append(list(x))    
        dataset=f.readline()

print(result)
```

(for python 3.7.4)